# Why is FUSE ESB (ServiceMix) 4.3 shutting down on linux if I leave karaf console?

Tags: java, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

I use ServiceMix 4.2 on my local Windows machine for development.

Now I installed a FUSE ESB 4.3 in a Linux environment and start it via SSHing on the linux machine. After leaving the karaf console the container always shuts down. How can I leave the karaf console with ServiceMix running?

(Might be just configuration, but I can't find it with Google or the FUSE docs)

Comment: Okay, for clarification: there is the "start" skript that only starts an instance of servicemix. There's the "servicemix" skript that starts the instance AND log me into the karaf console. But how can I get into the karaf console without shutting down the container if I leave it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start the (linux) servicemix instance with the 'start' script and afterwads remote connect to the console using ssh (e.g. from your windows FUSE session or a ssh client):

```
ssh:ssh {-l username} {-P password} {-p port} { hostname }
```

e.g.

```
karaf@root>ssh:ssh -l smx/karaf -P smx/karaf -p 8101 hostname
```

-l/-P default values depend on the FUSE version you are connecting to

-p is per default 8108

Use

```
karaf@root>shell:info
```

to determine which session you are currently logged in.

Have a look at the documentation [here](http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/runtime/ESBRuntimeConnect.html).

Answer (score 1):

The script servicemix accept some args, the one your looking for is "server".

Once servicemix started this way, you can log to the console using ssh.

You can found more args by editing servicemix startup script.

Bye,
Kev.